# SQLAlchemy: Get primary key of child table using unique key of it to use in main table

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have employee table and location table. All locations data is loaded into the table first. Then employee table will be loaded later using data from source system.

Tables:

Locations

### location_id(pk)| code(unique)| city | country

Employees

### emp_id(pk)| name| email | phone | location_id

Models(SQLAlchemy):

```
class Employee(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'employee'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   location_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('location.id'))
   location = relationship("Location")

class Location(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'location'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Employees data from source will have location code but while inserting into employee table I need location_id. I will be getting many records from source as part of API call. Is there a way I can use the location code and insert the data into employee table without DB call.
I have these two approaches - need a more optimized one.

1. Make call to DB using code and get location id for each employee.
2. Load all locations in memory in a map structure and use it to get location id for code.

Expecting something like

```
emp = Employee(name="a",email="a__@__.com",phone="123")
emp.location = Location(code="L1")  
db.session.add(emp)
db.session.commit()  
This should create employee record with location id corresponding to L1 code.
```

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining a mapping of location codes to ids or location objects is an entirely reasonable strategy if locations are not being added or removed from the database too frequently.

If you need to control the size of the cache you could use a function decorated with [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```python
import functools

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import orm

Base = declarative_base()


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    location = orm.relationship("Location")


class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'location'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = sa.Column(sa.String)


# Set echo=True on the engine so we can se the queries. 
engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///', echo=True)
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

session_factory = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = orm.scoped_session(session_factory)


@functools.lru_cache
def get_location_by_code(code):
    # We can proxy the session factory to avoid having to pass 
    # the session to this function (otherwise the session is part 
    # of the cache key, which we don't want).
    # We could add logic to handle a missing code.
    return Session.query(Location).filter_by(code=code).one()


# Add a location to the db
session = Session()
session.add(Location(code='L1'))
session.commit()
Session.remove()

# Add some employees to the database.
# Observe that we only query for location once.
session = Session()
for _ in range(3):
    employee = Employee()
    employee.location = get_location_by_code('L1')
    session.add(employee)
session.commit()
Session.remove()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It did help. But we have locations around 30k - just cannot cache these many records. Looking for any other alternatives.